# Python format float numbers like Fortran

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm printing some float numbers in Python and hope their output like Fortran `Fn.m` format, for example:

```py
# :some maybe format language like `F6.4` in Fortran
>>> '{:some}'.format(-0.0005)
-.0005
>>> '{:some}'.format(0.0005)
0.0005
```

I already know there is a module named `fortranformat` in PyPI can handle it, by I wonder if Python string-format language can solve my problem?

Comment: You mean that if you could display number `6478` as `64.78` if the format is `F4.2` ?

Comment: Fortran format `F6.4` means the output is 6-digit width  and the fraction after the decimal point is 4-digit width. Therefore, it can display number between -0.9999 ~ 9.9999 (a number between -0.9999~0 will only display the minus sign and the fraction with decimal point, e.g. `-.0005`), any number not in this range will be '******'.

Comment: Such a specific conditional formatting is not available in Python with format strings alone. It requires the aid of decision structures.

Answer (score 0):

Python's format mini-language has a concept of `width` and `precision`, but it only applies if the argument on which the format is applied to is already a float.

This can be done programatically though:

```
n = 6437
d = 2
res = "{}".format(n if d == 0 else n / (10 ** d))
```

which will yield: `64.37`

Answer (score 0):

My solution to friendly and compact float format for a UI is like this

```
def format_float(f):
    if f - float(int(f)) == 0.0:
        return str(int(f))
    s = ("%20.15f" % (f,).lstrip(" ").rstrip("0")
    return s
```

The point being that floats with no decimal digits look like integers, and leading spaces are removed, and trailing zeros are removed.
This makes the result string minimal width to get the idea across.
Useful in UI code.